# What is the full form of openVX?

Tags: openvx

What is the full form of openVX. What does `V` and `X` stand for in openVX.

(I have searched it in google and couldn't find the full form)

Answer (score 0):

I believe its [Vision Acceleration](https://www.khronos.org/openvx/)

Comment: from where `X` is coming in openVX ? It can be open Vision eXtension

Comment: as 'acceleration' sounds like 'X' and that why i believe.